# Deployment Diagram: "Deploy" a novel Execution Environment

Tags: java, deployment, environment, artifact

We’re at the conceptual design stage for a new Execution Environment. To keep things familiar, let's imagine it's a Java Runtime Environment. We start with the end in mind, and look ahead to it being a Nested Node within the OS Execution Environment. We'll call it *My Novel Java Runtime Environment*: [Novel EE after "deployment"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJC9Q.png)

Now we work out its logic. Presumably this is done by designing a biggish Component with interesting internal structure; we'll call this Component *My New JRE*. Its contents aren’t of interest here; perhaps the highest level is something like this:
[Novel EE as a Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74uIa.png)

The question is: **How does the Component turn into a nested Execution Environment?** In the ordinary English sense of the word, we want to “deploy” the *My New JRE* Component into the *OS* Execution Environment. The result should be a nested Execution Environment called *My Novel Java Runtime Environment*.

But in UML the result of deployment is an Artifact. I haven’t seen an Execution Environment, such as our novel one, being treated as an Artifact in UML. So I’m concerned about trouble with UML tools. What is the correct way to handle this “deployment” in UML?

Comment: Don't let the abstractions defined for UML limit your way of thinking. UML is a model, and models don't cover the complete real world, just some aspects. If you can't adequately describe it in UML, it can still exist.

Comment: That's encouraging. Thanks.